# Warning C4594 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, inheritance, visual-studio-2015

With the following code:

```
class A
{};

class B : virtual public A
{};

class C : private B
{};

class D : public C
{};
```

I get a compiler warning, which I have never seen in VS2012

```
warning C4594: 
class 'main::D' can never be instantiated- indirect virtual base class 'main::A' is inaccessible

note: 'main::A' is a public base class of 'main::B'

note: 'main::B' is a private base class of 'main::C'
```

Why do I get this?

My VS2015 Warning level is /W3, platform Toolset v140.

Comment: Why shouldn't the compiler issue this warning?

Comment: warning is correct, but why compiler VS2012 do not issue this warning?

Comment: That's an odd question. It's almost like asking, why they didn't send a Space Shuttle to rescue the Apollo 13 astronauts. Take a logical leap.

Comment: you mean that is a bug in vs2012 but corrected in vs2015?

Comment: Warnings are **completely optional**. A compiler doesn't have to emit warnings and can still be fully compliant. Warnings are there to make developers aware of effects of certain constructs, they may not have intended. Every release of a compiler tries to get better than the previous one, and adding warnings for previously uncaught potential errors is one way to improve. Mind you, the code in your question is perfectly legal, albeit useless. VC++ 2015 catches this for you, before anyone gets hurt.

Comment: Now the bug in VC++ 2012 is, that it actually compiled that code (just like Clang and GCC). That bug was fixed in VC++ 2015 Update 1. Some of that is discussed in the comments of this blog entry: [Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 RC Available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/10/29/visual-studio-2015-update-1-rc-available/).

Comment: Correction: That code is valid. The bug in VC++ prior to 2015 Update 1 was, that it compiled `D d;`. The bug is apparently still present in GCC 6.2 (haven't checked with Clang).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A virtual base class is initialized directly from the most derived class.

Therefore the code is invalid if the virtual base is inaccessible in the most derived class.

Comment: Slight nitpicking: The code is valid. Instantiating an object of type `D` would not be valid. Hence this is a warning, not an error message.

Comment: @IInspectable: You're right, thanks for mentioning. I was unsure about whether to edit in that after posting this answer. But I reasoned that the OP wouldn't be defining class D without using it for anything. Still. Hm.